# Homework assistance

Tags: javascript

Doing a Udemy course and need help with this question. Been on it for about a day, I am still really new, and trying to get a good grasp on JavaScript.

Here is the question.

> Please write a function called 'lastElement' which appears in a single array argument. The function should return the last element of the array (without removing the element). If the array is empty the function should return 'null'.

This is what I have written down so far and it works on my opera browser with Visual Studio Code. Also works with Chrome too, but I want to find out how my instructor wants me to get the right answer. Anyways here is my answer.

```
function lastElement(arr) {
    const jacob = arr[arr.length - 1];
    if (arr[arr.length - 1] >= 0) {
    console.log(jacob);
} else if (arr.length <= 0) {
        console.log(null);
    }
}
// These are the values i am checking.

1 |    lastElement([3,5,7]); //7
2 |    lastElement([1]); //1
3 |    lastElement([]); //null"
```

Comment: It looks like the task provides you to return a value from the function, not just log it to the console.

Comment: I don't wanna just post a solution, rather ask some questions that might help. Check your function, is it `return`ing anything? How would you check if the array is empty (then compare it with what the if/else does in your solution)?

Comment: Please note that your condition is wrong `if (arr[arr.length - 1] >= 0)`. This checks if the last array element is `>= 0`, not if the array is non-empty.

Comment: There is no reason to close this question because OP did an attempt by themselves and presented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the length first and if zero return `null`, because this is shorter than to get an element and then check the length.

```
if (arr.length === 0) return null;
```

For all other cases, return the last element. Here you need no `else` statement, because of the first condition's `return` statement.

```
return arr[arr.length - 1];
```

```js
function lastElement(array) {
    if (array.length === 0) return null;
    return array[array.length - 1];
}

console.log(lastElement([3, 5, 7])); //    7
console.log(lastElement([1]));       //    1
console.log(lastElement([]));        // null
```

Comment: why not return array.at(-1) ?

Answer (score 2):

Your instructor wants your function to actually `return` the last element, not only to `console.log` it:

```js
function lastElement(arr) {
  return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length ? arr[arr.length - 1] : null;
}

console.log(lastElement([3, 5, 7])); // 7
console.log(lastElement([1])); // 1
console.log(lastElement([])); // null
```

The reason that returning a value is useful is that you can e.g. assign the return value to a variable, or pass it to another function.

The latter is what actually happens in my example code:

```
console.log(lastElement([1]));
```

executes like this:

```
lastElement([1]) // this is called first and returns 1
```

Then the `return` value `1` is passed to `console.log`:

```
console.log(1)
```

Regarding the syntax I've used, that is called a ternary expression, and it is functionally identical to

```
if (Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length) { return arr[arr.length - 1]; }
else { return null; }
// same as
return Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length ? arr[arr.length - 1] : null;
```

Comment: First comment answered my question, thanks for the replies everyone.

Comment: Why not arr.at(-1) ?